# How can I wirite JUnit test to ensure Arraylist<POJO> records are correct?

Tags: android, junit, mockito, android-instrumentation

I have a method which prepare a list(ArrayList) based on the result of a query.But how can I write test cases to ensure the number and type of records in the list are correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just checked the size of list is correct as I expected. But How can we check the records are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the Assertion library that you're using. If you use the JUnit `Assert` class then you can use `assertEquals`.

```
@Test
public void theListIsOk() {
  List<SomeClass> list = sut.getList();
  assertEquals(
    list,
    Arrays.asList(
      new SomeClass(),
      new SomeClass(),
      new SomeClass()
    )
  );
)
```

The prerequisite is that `SomeClass` has a proper `equals` method.